# How to set divider between spinner each item?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I looking for some solutions and try to complete it. The divider still doesn't show out.

I have set style for my theme in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Others theme here. -->
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/mySpinnerStyle</item>
</style>
```

Here is mySpinnerStyle

```
<style name="mySpinnerStyle" parent="android:Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Here is my fragment code for spinner:

```
Spinner chooseDate = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.chooseDate);

String[] date_group = dateList.toArray(new String[dateList.size()]);
            ArrayAdapter<String> itemDate = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner, date_group);
            itemDate.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner);
            chooseDate.setAdapter(itemDate);
```

Here is my spinner layout xml:

```
<Spinner
            android:theme="@style/mySpinnerStyle"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/chooseDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_arrow" />
```

And then R.layout.spinner xml is like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:theme="@style/mySpinnerStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

I click my spinner shows dialog like this that is no divider in the end...
[image]

I have set style for my spinner but i can't show divider. I don't know why ?

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advnace.

Manifests use my AppTheme:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_512x512"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

Comment: did you try removing the background of your Spinner?

Comment: Yes, its no working. The background setting just change my spinner border.

Comment: and Does your activity is using your "AppTheme" in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes , my manifests use this `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` just like my question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `android:theme="@style/mySpinnerStyle"` from your `TextView` (R.layout.spinner xml)

And change this value from your `spinner`

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

Use this value

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

Comment: Yeap, that thing i was trying to remember. cool buddy nice answer +1

Comment: Thank you . Divider show out finally. But can i set a dialog for spinner in my case ?  The style setting `android:Widget.ListView.DropDown` i can't find Dialog.

Answer (score 6):

This may help you,

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#effbe4"
    >
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_item_border"
    />
```

**spinner_item_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff2632"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#d7ffa2"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**In Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get reference of widgets from XML layout
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // Initializing a String Array
    String[] plants = new String[]{
            "Black birch",
            "Bolean birch",
            "Canoe birch",
            "Cherry birch",
            "European weeping birch"
    };

    // Initializing an ArrayAdapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,R.layout.spinner_item,plants
    );
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Set a background for spinner_item.xml is another way . I even't find that !  Thank you again.

Comment: Ok Happy coding !

Answer (score 5):

Show divider into spinner item need to set two property into linear layout
1. **Divider and show dividers** check below code.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
android:showDividers="end"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp5"
    android:textColor="#6F6F6F"

    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp5" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: It is Working fine. Thanks for sharing.